# Qlik Sense : SQL With Statement

Tags: sql, reporting, common-table-expression, qliksense

I'm using Qlik Sense Desktop in order to create reportings.
However, i want to load datas using this request :

```
WITH ventes AS (SELECT        Reservations.re_numero AS IDSession, InscriptionsLignes.il_montantLigneHT AS VenteSession, Reservations.re_nom AS NomSession, Tiers.ti_nom AS NomClient, CASE WHEN Tiers_2.ti_nom + ' ' + Tiers_2.ti_prenom IS NULL THEN 'Non affecté' ELSE Tiers_2.ti_nom + ' ' + Tiers_2.ti_prenom END AS NomCommercial
                                     FROM            Reservations INNER JOIN
                                                               InscriptionsEntetes ON Reservations.re_numero = InscriptionsEntetes.in_reservation INNER JOIN
                                                               InscriptionsLignes ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_numero = InscriptionsLignes.il_inscription INNER JOIN
                                                               InscriptionsTiers ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_numero = InscriptionsTiers.it_inscription AND InscriptionsLignes.il_inscription = InscriptionsTiers.it_inscription INNER JOIN
                                   Tiers ON InscriptionsTiers.it_tiers = Tiers.ti_identifiant LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                   Tiers AS Tiers_2 ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_idTiersConseiller = Tiers_2.ti_identifiant
                                     WHERE        (InscriptionsTiers.it_typeRattachement = '01') AND (Reservations.re_etat <> 3) AND (Reservations.re_annulation = 0) AND (InscriptionsEntetes.in_Etat <> '4')), couts AS
    (SELECT        Reservations_1.re_numero AS IDSession, ReservationsProduits.rp_montantPrevu AS Couts
      FROM            Reservations AS Reservations_1 INNER JOIN
                                ReservationsProduits ON Reservations_1.re_numero = ReservationsProduits.rp_numeroReservation
      WHERE        (Reservations_1.re_etat <> 3) AND (Reservations_1.re_annulation = 0)), tot_couts AS
    (SELECT        IDSession, SUM(Couts) AS couts_total
      FROM            couts AS couts_1
      GROUP BY IDSession), tot_ventes AS
    (SELECT        IDSession, SUM(VenteSession) AS ventes_total
      FROM            ventes AS ventes_1
      GROUP BY IDSession)
    SELECT        tvn.IDSession, tvn.ventes_total, tct.couts_total, ventes_2.NomSession, ventes_2.NomClient, ventes_2.VenteSession, ventes_2.VenteSession - tct.couts_total / (tvn.ventes_total / ventes_2.VenteSession) AS marge
     FROM            tot_ventes AS tvn INNER JOIN
                              tot_couts AS tct ON tvn.IDSession = tct.IDSession INNER JOIN
                              ventes AS ventes_2 ON tvn.IDSession = ventes_2.IDSession
     WHERE        (ventes_2.VenteSession <> 0)
     ORDER BY tvn.IDSession
```

As you can see, I'm using the SQL With Statement but it doesn't work on Qlik, "With" is a unknown statement they said

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Some sql commands are just recongnize in Qlik if you use the SQL statement before, e.g.:

TableName:
LOAD *;
 SQL ;

```
    TableName:
    LOAD *;
    SQL
    WITH ventes AS (
         SELECT Reservations.re_numero AS IDSession
              , InscriptionsLignes.il_montantLigneHT AS VenteSession
              , Reservations.re_nom AS NomSession
              , Tiers.ti_nom AS NomClient
              , CASE 
                  WHEN Tiers_2.ti_nom + ' ' + Tiers_2.ti_prenom IS NULL 
                  THEN 'Non affecté' 
                  ELSE Tiers_2.ti_nom + ' ' + Tiers_2.ti_prenom 
                END AS NomCommercial
          FROM Reservations 
         INNER JOIN InscriptionsEntetes 
            ON Reservations.re_numero = InscriptionsEntetes.in_reservation 
         INNER JOIN InscriptionsLignes 
            ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_numero = InscriptionsLignes.il_inscription 
         INNER JOIN InscriptionsTiers 
            ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_numero = InscriptionsTiers.it_inscription 
           AND InscriptionsLignes.il_inscription = InscriptionsTiers.it_inscription 
         INNER JOIN Tiers 
            ON InscriptionsTiers.it_tiers = Tiers.ti_identifiant 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Tiers AS Tiers_2 
            ON InscriptionsEntetes.in_idTiersConseiller = Tiers_2.ti_identifiant
         WHERE (InscriptionsTiers.it_typeRattachement = '01') 
           AND (Reservations.re_etat  3) 
           AND (Reservations.re_annulation = 0) 
           AND (InscriptionsEntetes.in_Etat  '4'))
              , couts AS
        (SELECT Reservations_1.re_numero AS IDSession
              , ReservationsProduits.rp_montantPrevu AS Couts
          FROM Reservations AS Reservations_1 
         INNER JOIN ReservationsProduits 
            ON Reservations_1.re_numero = ReservationsProduits.rp_numeroReservation
         WHERE (Reservations_1.re_etat  3) 
           AND (Reservations_1.re_annulation = 0)), tot_couts AS
        (SELECT IDSession, SUM(Couts) AS couts_total
           FROM couts AS couts_1
          GROUP BY IDSession), tot_ventes AS
        (SELECT IDSession, SUM(VenteSession) AS ventes_total
           FROM ventes AS ventes_1
          GROUP BY IDSession)
        SELECT tvn.IDSession
             , tvn.ventes_total
             , tct.couts_total
             , ventes_2.NomSession
             , ventes_2.NomClient
             , ventes_2.VenteSession
             , ventes_2.VenteSession - tct.couts_total / (tvn.ventes_total / ventes_2.VenteSession) AS marge
          FROM tot_ventes AS tvn 
         INNER JOIN tot_couts AS tct 
            ON tvn.IDSession = tct.IDSession 
         INNER JOIN ventes AS ventes_2 
            ON tvn.IDSession = ventes_2.IDSession
         WHERE (ventes_2.VenteSession  0)
         ORDER BY tvn.IDSession;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your query in a parent one:

```
TableName:
Load *;
SQL
select *
from (
  --put your WITH query here
) as temp;
```

Depending on your RDBMS you might not need this final alias ("as temp").